# Most frequent number in vector

Tags: r

I have a vector `a<-replicate(100, round(runif(1)))`

I would like to count which is more frequent 0 or 1.

I could use `table(a)` but is there a more direct way to display the most frequently occurring number?

My problem with table(a):

`a` is generated several times in the program and the most frequent number is recorded on each iteration. If I use `table(a)` the first column will have the count of `0`s and the 2nd column the count of `1`s. Now I use `b<-as.vector(table(a))` to directly get the counts and use `b[1]` as the number of 0s and `b[2]` as the number of 1s. Now if it happens that there are only 1s or only 0s in the vector then the length of b will be 1 and I will have no idea wether I have 100 1s or 100 0s.

Comment: `table(a)` seems pretty direct to me. What problem exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: ftable(a) would give a more attractive display

Comment: please see my edit where I explain my problem with tables

Comment: What about `tabulate`. In this case, it will just return the count of ones. Some basic comparison with the length of a would tell you whether there are more ones or zeroes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just `sum(a)`? If `sum(a) > 50`, 1 is more frequent. It's a common technique for boolean values.

Comment: `mean(a) > .5` would work regardless of the length of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the table in a `data.frame` and then use `which.max`

```
adf<-data.frame(table(a))
adf[which.max(adf$Freq),1]
```

Comment: Do you really need `data.frame`? `table(a)[which.max(table(a))]`?

Comment: perhaps this can be a solution as.vector(names(table(a)[which.max(table(a))]))